# Show users that reacted to a message with a ReactionCollector

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a "vote" command where you can see who voted. This is my current code:

```
message.channel.send("React with  to vote").then(Msent =>
  Msent.react('')).then(Msent => {
  const collector = Msent.message.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '', {
    time: 15000
  });

  collector.on('collect', r => {
    if (r.emoji.name === '') {
      message.channel.send("someone voted!");
    }
  });
  collector.on('end', collected => {
    message.channel.send(`${collected.size} users voted`);
  });
})
```

I've been trying to replace "someone voted!" with the name of the user who voted: how can I do this?

Another thing is that `collected.size` is `0` if no one reacted, but its always `1` no matter if 1 or 5 users reacted: what am I doing wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been trying to replace "someone voted!" with the name of the user who voted: how can I do this?

You can't get the user from the 'collect' event handler because the parameter is a `MessageReaction`: you can only get **all** the users that reacted.
The only thing you can do is modify the filter to something like this:

```
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
    message.channel.send(`${user} voted!`); // This will mention the user
    message.channel.send(`${user.tag} voted!`); // This will only say their name
    return true;
  } else return false;
}
const collector = Msent.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });
```

---

> `collected.size` is `0` if no one reacted, but its always 1 no matter if 1 or 5 users reacted: what am I doing wrong there?

The problem is that `collected` contains the collected **reactions**, not the users, and since your filter accepts only one emoji its `size` will only be `0` or `1`.
To  get the number of users you need to check for [`MessageReaction.users.size`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=users):

```
collector.on('end', collected => {
  let n_users = 0;
  if (collected.size > 0) { // Check if there was any vote
    let reaction = collected.first(); // Take the first (and only) 'type' of reaction
    n_users = reaction.users.size; // Get the number of users that used it
  }
  message.channel.send(`${n_users} users voted`);
});
```

Comment: Happy to hear that :)